# What's the meaning of "there" in the end of this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

I've seen this sentence somewhere:

> "You don't need to launch a formal campaign to start getting your message out there."

What is "there" in this case?

Answer (score 2):

The word 'out' in the phrase "something is out" means that something is available, is in circulation, etc. See [definition 17 of out](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/out).

The related phrases "to put something out" and "to get something out" mean to take an action that makes something "out". I.e., to make something available, to cause it to be in circulation, etc. See the entries for "put" and "get", respectively, to learn how these phrases are used.

As for appending "there" to this phrase; it specifies the location (a destination, in this case) where you're performing the action of putting/getting something out (without explicitly stating the location). For example,

> to get your message out onto all the major social media platforms

> to get your message out into the world

> to get your message out **there**

For these phrases ("get something out" and "put something out"), you can also omit the location completely, and the location will be understood as being generally available:

> to get your message out

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation!